# Does the order of fields in a WHERE clause affect performance in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, performance

I have two indexed fields in a table - `type` and `userid` (individual indexes, not a composite).

`type`s field values are very limited (let's say it is only 0 or 1), so 50% of table records have the same `type`. `userid` values, on the other hand, come from a much larger set, so the amount of records with the same `userid` is small.

Will any of these queries run faster than the other:

```
select * from table where type=1 and userid=5
select * from table where userid=5 and type=1
```

Also if both fields were not indexed, would it change the behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does order of where clauses matter in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436469/does-order-of-where-clauses-matter-in-sql)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

SQL was designed to be a declarative language, not a procedural one.  So the query optimizer should **not** consider the order of the where clause predicates in determining how to apply them.

I'm probably going to waaaay over-simplify the following discussion of an SQL query optimizer.  I wrote one years ago, along these lines (it was tons of fun!). If you really want to dig into modern query optimization, see Dan Tow's [SQL Tuning](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0-596-00573-3), from O'Reilly.

In a simple SQL query optimizer, the SQL statement first gets compiled into a tree of *relational algebra* operations.  These operations each take one or more tables as input and produce another table as output.  *Scan* is a sequential scan that reads a table in from the database.  *Sort* produces a sorted table. *Select* produces a table whose rows are selected from another table according to some selection condition. *Project* produces a table with only certain columns of another table.  *Cross Product* takes two tables and produces an output table composed of every conceivable pairing of their rows.

Confusingly, the SQL SELECT clause is compiled into a relational algebra *Project*, while the WHERE clause turns into a relational algebra *Select*.  The FROM clause turns into one or more *Joins*, each taking two tables in and producing one table out.  There are other relational algebra operations involving set union, intersection, difference, and membership, but let's keep this simple.

This tree really needs to be optimized.  For example, if you have:

```
select E.name, D.name 
from Employee E, Department D 
where E.id = 123456 and E.dept_id = D.dept_id
```

with 5,000 employees in 500 departments, executing an unoptimized tree will blindly produce all possible combinations of one Employee and one Department (a *Cross Product*) and then *Select* out just the one combination that was needed.  The *Scan* of Employee will produce a 5,000 record table, the *Scan* of Department will produce a 500 record table, the *Cross Product* of those two tables will produce a 2,500,000 record table, and the *Select* on E.id will take that 2,500,000 record table and discard all but one, the record that was wanted.

[Real query processors will try not to materialize all of these intermediate tables in memory of course.]

So the query optimizer walks the tree and applies various optimizations.  One is to break up each *Select* into a chain of *Selects*, one for each of the original *Select*'s top level conditions, the ones and-ed together.  (This is called "conjunctive normal form".)  Then the individual smaller *Selects* are moved around in the tree and merged with other relational algebra operations to form more efficient ones.

In the above example, the optimizer first pushes the *Select* on E.id = 123456 down below the expensive *Cross Product* operation.  This means the *Cross Product* just produces 500 rows (one for each combination of that employee and one department).  Then the top level *Select* for E.dept_id = D.dept_id filters out the 499 unwanted rows.  Not bad.

If there's an an index on Employee's id field, then the optimizer can combine the *Scan* of Employee with the *Select* on E.id = 123456 to form a fast index *Lookup*.  This means that only one Employee row is read into memory from disk instead of 5,000.  Things are looking up.

The final major optimization is to take the *Select* on E.dept_id = D.dept_id and combine it with the *Cross Product*.  This turns it into a relational algebra *Equijoin* operation.  This doesn't do much by itself.  But if there's an index on Department.dept_id, then the lower level sequential *Scan* of Department feeding the *Equijoin* can be turned into a very fast index *Lookup* of our one employee's Department record.

Lesser optimizations involve pushing *Project* operations down.  If the top level of your query just needs E.name and D.name, and the conditions need E.id, E.dept_id, and D.dept_id, then the *Scan* operations don't have to build intermediate tables with all the other columns, saving space during the query execution.  We've turned a horribly slow query into two index lookups and not much else.

Getting more towards the original question, let's say you've got:

```
select E.name 
from Employee E 
where E.age > 21 and E.state = 'Delaware'
```

The unoptimized relational algebra tree, when executed, would Scan in the 5,000 employees and produce, say, the 126 ones in Delaware who are older than 21.  The query optimizer also has some rough idea of the values in the database.  It might know that the E.state column has the 14 states that the company has locations in, and something about the E.age distributions.  So first it sees if either field is indexed.  If E.state is, it makes sense to use that index to just pick out the small number of employees the query processor suspects are in Delaware based on its last computed statistics.  If only E.age is, the query processor likely decides that it's not worth it, since 96% of all employees are 22 and older.  So if E.state is indexed, our query processor breaks the *Select* and merges the E.state = 'Delaware' with the *Scan* to turn it into a much more efficient *Index Scan*.

Let's say in this example that there are no indexes on E.state and E.age.  The combined *Select* operation takes place after the sequential "Scan" of Employee.  Does it make a difference which condition in the *Select* is done first?  Probably not a great deal.  The query processor might leave them in the original order in the SQL statement, or it might be a bit more sophisticated and look at the expected expense.  From the statistics, it would again find that the E.state = 'Delaware' condition should be more highly selective, so it would reverse the conditions and do that first, so that there are only 126 E.age > 21 comparisons instead of 5,000.  Or it might realize that string equality comparisons are much more expensive than integer compares and leave the order alone.

At any rate, all this is very complex and your syntactic condition order is very unlikely to make a difference.  I wouldn't worry about it unless you have a real performance problem and your database vendor uses the condition order as a hint.

Answer (score 12):

Most query optimizers use the order in which conditions appear as a hint.  If everything else is equal, they will follow that order.

However, many things can override that:

- the second field has an index and the first has not
- there are statistics to suggest that field 2 is more selective
- the second field is easier to search (`varchar(max)` vs `int`)

So (and this is true for all SQL optimization questions) unless you observe a performance issue, it's better to optimize for clarity, not for (imagined) performance.

Comment: It doesn't cost anything to make such optimization, so why not if it matters. So what is better - userid first and type after?

Comment: @serg: Well 95% of the time MySQL will correctly choose userid, 4% it will choose typeid; for the remaining 1%, you could put typeid first :)

Comment: @Andomar Posting in an old thread. Where did you get those numbers 95% vs 4% vs 1%? Or were you just making them up?

Comment: @Andomar - great example of how to, and how not to, optimize.

Answer (score 7):

It shouldn't in your small example. The query optimizer should do the right thing. You can check for sure by adding `explain` to the front of the query. MySQL will tell you how it's joining things together and how many rows it needs to search in order to do the join. For example:

`explain select * from table where type=1 and userid=5`

If they were not indexed it would probably change behavior.