# Order of WHERE constraints in query

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the order of fields in a WHERE clause affect performance in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035760/does-the-order-of-fields-in-a-where-clause-affect-performance-in-mysql)

Does the order of the elements in a WHERE clause change the speed of the query?

I have the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE a<b
```

.  This returns 500 records.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE c<d
```

.  This returns 130000000 records.

Now, if you have a choice between:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE a<b AND c<d
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE c<d AND a<b
```

Which of these 2 queries will be faster?  Does the order matter?

Comment: Order of the predicates makes no difference.

Comment: But doesn't mysql do the constraints one after the other.  In which case I would guess the first will be faster because it leaves less entries for the second constraint to work on?

Comment: I might just get a lucky result.  I want to know for sure...

Comment: Empirical testing is the *only* way to know for sure...

Answer (score 3):

The only time it would affect performance is with indexes.

If you have an index on `(a, c)`, a predicate of `WHERE c < d AND a < b` would run slower since the index goes left to right.

If you do not have an index, the order does not matter.

Comment: Absolutely. The speed of the query well depend on the indices of the table and the engine the table is running on.

Comment: Removed downvote following edit but will be surprised if this is correct and MySQL can't rearrange predicates as it sees fit.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks. I'm more versed with SQL Server performance, and I know for a fact the index will *not* be used if the order doesn't go with the 'left-to-right' of an index.

Comment: The question is asking about `c < d AND a < b` vs `a < b AND c < d` though. They are the same predicates just the order reversed. In SQL Server it definitely does not make any difference what order they appear in the query.

Comment: @Martin How does mysql decide which to do first?  Does it precompute the expected number of rows for each constraint?  how does it know?

Comment: @MartinSmith [This excerpt](http://books.google.com/books?id=FcW6hYmH6FgC&pg=PT176&lpg=PT176&dq=%22Furthermore,+while+creating+an+index+on+multiple+columns,+which+is+also+referred+to+as+a+composite+index,+column+order+matters.%22&source=bl&ots=gSHachxYep&sig=SIPalKYa-5758_n_Imp-pYVvtFU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pCuRUIq_H_KvygHe4oC4Ag&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA) is what I'm going off of.

Comment: @njk - Yes column order matters **in the index definition** (if you have an index on `last name, first name` it won't help queries on first name) but the question is about rearranging **the same** predicates in the query. SQL Server wouldn't care if you wrote the query as `last-name='foo' and first_name='bar'` or `first-name='bar' and last_name='foo'`

Comment: @David19801 I would recommend reading [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4035997/679449) regarding how the optimizer works.

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm in agreement.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no difference. Just like in MATH, `A + B = B + C`. It just means that interchanging both doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I believe he is talking about the speed of the query, not the result set.

Comment: @Darrrrrren i didn't say about result set. I just illustrate that interchanging both don't have any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so there will be any difference, it will be optimalized by the sql anyway. 
More info here at this question: [Does the order of fields in a WHERE clause affect performance in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035760/does-the-order-of-fields-in-a-where-clause-affect-performance-in-mysql)