# SQL Server : Multiple Where Clauses

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have a T-SQL command with multiple `WHERE` conditions like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName
WHERE Column1 NOT LIKE '%exclude%'
  AND Column2 > 10
```

Would the query exclude a row as soon as `Column1` was not met or would it still go on to test the next condition for `Column2`?

I am asking because I want to see if it would be more efficient to swap my conditions around to first test if `Column2 > 10` before I run a more time-consuming condition.

Edit: If it matters, `Column1` is of type `bigint` and `Column2` is of type `ntext`

Comment: I would also add any indexes that may be on the table into the question

Comment: SQL is a declarative language, and not a procedural one. The query optimizer doesn't consider the order of the where clauses. 
Your answer might be here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035760/does-the-order-of-fields-in-a-where-clause-affect-performance-in-mysql

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sql will devise a query plan based on available indexes and statistics.  Sql doesn't necessarily have "short-circuit" expression evaluation per se because it is a procedural language but ultimately the query plan will perform short-circuit evaluation.

Swapping the expressions should not affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

As Marc said, swapping columns in where clause will not make any change in performance. Instead, you could look for changing the data type NTEXT into nvarchar(X) where x represents some meaningful data length.

Comment: Unfortunately for my specific use, this will not work because I only have read-only access to the DB